# SSPI SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL with bad SPN

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, credentials, sspi

With SSPI, I'm trying to connect my win7 to a win2008-r2 domain controller.

The win7 is connected to the DC without any problem.

So, on domain controller I create a new SPN

```
C:\> setspn -A test/value vmlab-wdc01
```

I check the new entry

```
 C:\setspn -l vmlab-wdc01
 Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=VMLAB-WDC01,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=vmlab,DC=local:
         test/value
         ldap/vmlab-wdc01.vmlab.local/ForestDnsZones.vmlab.local
         ldap/vmlab-wdc01.vmlab.local/DomainDnsZones.vmlab.local
         TERMSRV/VMLAB-WDC01
         TERMSRV/vmlab-wdc01.vmlab.local
         Dfsr-12F9A27C-BF97-4787-9364-D31B6C55EB04/vmlab-wdc01.vmlab.local
         DNS/vmlab-wdc01.vmlab.local
         GC/vmlab-wdc01.vmlab.local/vmlab.local
         HOST/vmlab-wdc01.vmlab.local/VMLAB
         HOST/vmlab-wdc01.vmlab.local
         ldap/vmlab-wdc01.vmlab.local/VMLAB
         ldap/VMLAB-WDC01
         ldap/vmlab-wdc01.vmlab.local
         ldap/vmlab-wdc01.vmlab.local/vmlab.local
```

Now, on client side I call 
  InitializeSecurityContext( hCred, NULL, "test/value" ...

And I get SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL

I tried ldap/vmlab-wdc01.vmlab.local too, same results
If I juste Tried "Administrator", it works !!

what's wrong ...